# kotlin, where the return from inside the let go

Tags: kotlin, let

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    return block(this)
}
```

and have a function like:

```
fun getType() : String? {

     val type = mContent.let {
         if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(it) && it == "TYPE_1") {
             return "TYPE_A" . //where it returns to, as the result of the let{},  or as return value to exit the fun getType()?
         }
         else {
            return it
         }
     }

     if (type == "TYPE_A") {
        return getType_A() 
     } 

     return type
}
```

where does the return inside the block in the let go{}, exit the `fun getType()` or just return from the `let{}`?

Answer (score 10):

The rule in Kotlin is that **a plain `return` returns from the nearest enclosing `fun`** in your code.

See the language docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html).

If there's an enclosing lambda, then that's only possible if the lambda is inline (i.e. passed to a function marked with the `inline` keyword); otherwise the compiler will complain.

You can change that if needed by qualifying the return with an enclosing label (e.g. `return@myLabel`) or function name (e.g. `return@let`).  But if it's not qualified, you just need to look for the nearest enclosing function defined with `fun`.

Comment: isnt the `inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R` . also a `fun`?     what about the `block`  is   a function defined somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, `let()` is defined as a `fun` — but that's elsewhere.  The rule looks for the keyword `fun` _in your code_.  Which, in this example, means `fun getType() : String?`.